# Injective Homomorphism from a group into $GL_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$|G|=n\ge 2<\infty,$ A group, I need to know which of the followings are true?

1. $\exists$ allways an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_n$
2. $\exists$ allways an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_m$ forsome $m<n$
3. $\exists$ allways an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

$1$ is false, $2$ is true (Cayley's theorem), but I have no idea how to define such a map for $3$ if it exists.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well 2 implies 1, so you did something wrong already...

Comment: ooooooooooops sorrrrrrrry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $2\Rightarrow 1$, so if 2 is true then so is 1. Also, $1\Rightarrow 3$ since the permutation matrices (the matrices that have all entries 0 except for exactly one 1 in each row and column) form a subgroup of the general linear group isomorphic to $S_n$. 1 is true by Cayley's theorem, but 2 is false as witnessed by the cyclic group of order 3.

As hinted by Hagen, the permutation matrices permute the elements of a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate a bit for the answer of 3, and thanks for 1,2 I have understood 1,2

Comment: @FemmeDouce my edit above clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your guesses for 1 and 2 are both wrong. For 3, try to find an injective homomorphism $S_n\to GL_n(\mathbb R)$. **Hint:** $S_n$ acts on an $n$-element set. What $n$-element thingy does an $n$-dimensional space have by definition?

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate a bit for the answer of $3$, and thanks for $1,2$ I have understood 1,2